# Multiline value inside ConvertFrom-StringData

Tags: powershell

I need to store a multiline string inside my Powershell language translation file, so i tried this

```
ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData @'

msg_first = Ok1
msg_two = @"
Ok2
Nok2
"@

'@
```

but prompt show a Import-LocalizedData error and say that first line of msg_two are not in correct format. If not possible, what is the good alternative ?

Comment: `msg_two = Ok2\nNok2` -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7.3#example-7-use-escape-characters-to-add-new-lines-and-return-characters

Comment: You could use a PowerShellDataFile and the according cmdlet `Import-PowerShellDataFile`. There you can save a multi line value ... even when it looks weird because of the needed formatting of the here string.  ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

as Zett42 answered, I guess at the first place you use not correct Format of Code!
"first line of msg_two are not in correct format" may means that you do not need "@" but anyway you have wrong format and it is a compiler error not a logic, etc.
but as you questioned what is other ways, I think "hash table" is easier to use why you do not use it?

```html
$myMessages = @{msg_first = "Ok1"
                msg_two = "Ok2`nNok2"}
```

then you can use it in function paramerter,save it in powershell data file or directly as a variable in your script.

Comment: Just FYI - zelocalhost tried to use a here string to save a multi line string. ☝